# How can I iterate a date column to check for criteria in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL Server 2008 database, I'm trying to identify each ID that has corresponding dates that meet the following criteria:

1. Are any 2 dates within each ID >= 3 months apart?
2. Are those same 2 dates <= 24 months apart?

I can do a comparison on the next row, but that doesn't tell me if rows 1 and 3 meet the criteria, or rows 5 and 7, etc.

Here's the table structure (there are around 100,000 rows in the actual table):

```
select ID, Date from #tmp;

ID  Date
ID1 7/2/2016
ID1 10/19/2016
ID1 1/21/2017
ID1 7/19/2017
ID2 11/26/2015
ID2 2/10/2016
ID2 5/23/2016
ID3 6/15/2017
ID3 6/30/2017
```

So here ID1 and ID2 both have dates meeting the criteria, but the dates for ID3 don't meet the 1st criteria (being 3 months apart).

Here's the self-join I've tried so far:

```
with NextDateTable as
(
select
ID
,Date
,rn=rank() over (partition by ID order by Date asc)
from #tmp
)
select
a.ID
,a.Date
,NextDate=b.Date
into #tmp2
from NextDateTable a
left join NextDateTable b on a.ID=b.ID and b.rn=a.rn+1
order by ID,Date
;
```

This gives me a table with the next date in a new column, so I can do the following datediff:

```
select 
ID
,Date
,NextDate
,case
when ((Date is not null) and (NextDate is not null))
 and 
    datediff(mm,Date,NextDate)>=3
and
    datediff(mm,Date,NextDate)<=24
then 1
else 0
end as Check
into #tmp3
from #tmp2
;
```

The problem with this is that it only checks consecutive rows, and it doesn't check every row against each other row within the same ID.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could this be done with cursors and while loops?

Answer (score 1):

Your question simplifies to asking if the total span of the dates is between 3 and 24 months.  You can simply do:

```
select id
from #tmp
group by id
having max(date) >= dateadd(month, 3, min(date)) and
       max(date) < dateadd(month, 24, min(date));
```

Note that if you are asking about *adjacent* dates, then that is another question, not this one.  Ask a new question if that is what you really intend.

Comment: The problem with this is if the total span of the dates is more than 24 months, but there exist 2 dates in between the span less than 24 months apart, then this wouldn't pick that up. E.g. 1/1/2015, 1/2/2015, 5/3/2015, 3/26/2018.